# HTTPConnection for blackberries experiencing intermittent connection

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection

I'm connecting to an ASP.NET webservice using the HTTPConnection class in Blackberry, but when the blackberry is experiencing low signal strength, the connection just keeps waiting for a response from the server. I've tried timeouts, but with intermittent connections, they're not really helping.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem before?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making the call, checking for `coverageinfo.iscoveragesufficient` fixes a lot of issues.